# Aligning Bootstrap cards / panels of different height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am developing a web site that will show news articles. On the front page each new article will be presented in a panel/card/box. I am using Bootstraps grid system to make my panels. Unfortunately the panels get stacked very strange if they have different height.

This image shows the issue more clearly:

[image]

Live demo: http://www.runarb.com/div/bootstack.html

How do I get the panels to stack nice like the first part in my image and not with all the wasted space like in the bottom part?

Comment: Can we change the markup?

Comment: Sure. I am quite early in the project so any suggestion to change is must appreciated.

Comment: Have a read over bootstrap vertical alignment guide https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your preferred layout can be implemented by wrapping a container for every four `div` elements. Not relevant to the answer but there is no class `col-xs-18` by default for Twitter Bootstrap.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/engusabn/1/embedded/result/)

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<hr>
<div class="row">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/500x250/EEE">
        <div class="caption">
          <h4>Thumbnail label</h4>

          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, soluta, eligendi doloribus sunt minus amet sit debitis repellat. Consectetur, culpa itaque odio similique suscipit</p> <a role="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right"
          href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>  <a role="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" href="#">Button</a>  <a role="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" href="#">Button</a>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/500x250/EEE">
        <div class="caption">
          <h4>Thumbnail label</h4>

          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, soluta, eligendi doloribus sunt minus amet sit debitis repellat. Consectetur, culpa itaque odio similique suscipit</p> <a role="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right"
          href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>  <a role="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" href="#">Button</a>  <a role="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" href="#">Button</a>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/500x250/EEE">
        <div class="caption">
          <h4>Thumbnail label</h4>

          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, soluta, eligendi doloribus sunt minus amet sit debitis repellat. Consectetur, culpa itaque odio similique suscipit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere,
            soluta, eligendi doloribus sunt minus amet sit debitis repellat. Consectetur, culpa itaque odio similique suscipit</p> <a role="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right" href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>  <a role="button"
          class="btn btn-info btn-xs" href="#">Button</a>  <a role="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" href="#">Button</a>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/500x250/EEE">
        <div class="caption">
          <h4>Thumbnail label</h4>

          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, soluta, eligendi doloribus sunt minus amet sit debitis repellat. Consectetur, culpa itaque odio similique suscipit</p> <a role="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right"
          href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>  <a role="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" href="#">Button</a>  <a role="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" href="#">Button</a>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/500x250/EEE">
        <div class="caption">
          <h4>Thumbnail label</h4>

          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, soluta, eligendi doloribus sunt minus amet sit debitis repellat. Consectetur, culpa itaque odio similique suscipit</p> <a role="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right"
          href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>  <a role="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" href="#">Button</a>  <a role="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" href="#">Button</a>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/500x250/EEE">
        <div class="caption">
          <h4>Thumbnail label</h4>

          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, soluta, eligendi doloribus sunt minus amet sit debitis repellat. Consectetur, culpa itaque odio similique suscipit</p> <a role="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right"
          href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>  <a role="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" href="#">Button</a>  <a role="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" href="#">Button</a>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/500x250/EEE">
        <div class="caption">
          <h4>Thumbnail label</h4>

          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, soluta, eligendi doloribus sunt minus amet sit debitis repellat. Consectetur, culpa itaque odio similique suscipit</p> <a role="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right"
          href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>  <a role="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" href="#">Button</a>  <a role="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" href="#">Button</a>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/500x250/EEE">
        <div class="caption">
          <h4>Thumbnail label</h4>

          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, soluta, eligendi doloribus sunt minus amet sit debitis repellat. Consectetur, culpa itaque odio similique suscipit</p> <a role="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right"
          href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>  <a role="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" href="#">Button</a>  <a role="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" href="#">Button</a>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--/row-->
```

Answer (score 0):

The quickest fix for your issue would be to actually use more rows.

Right now, you have the following structure :

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-3">...</div>
   <div class="col-md-3">...</div>
   <div class="col-md-3">...</div>
   <div class="col-md-3">...</div>
   <div class="col-md-3">...</div>
   <div class="col-md-3">...</div>
   <div class="col-md-3">...</div>
   <div class="col-md-3">...</div>
</div>
```

It might behave like a grid, but all you have here is only a single row.

Try just to modify it like so :

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-3">...</div>
   <div class="col-md-3">...</div>
   <div class="col-md-3">...</div>
   <div class="col-md-3">...</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-3">...</div>
   <div class="col-md-3">...</div>
   <div class="col-md-3">...</div>
   <div class="col-md-3">...</div>
</div>
```

That should solve your issue.